# Generate PDF with cyrillic (or UTF-8) contents

Tags: pdf-generation

My C# .NET 3.5 application has an option to export text to PDF. I am using ReportingCloud (based on RDL) as generation engine. However, cyrillic texts shown incorrectly in resulting PDF. What means can I use to generate cyrillic PDF correctly? A method to generate UTF8 will also do.

UPD: Particularly, how to embed right fonts into PDF?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with ReportingCloud, so perhaps this is not the easiest answer to your question. But for really great looking PDFs with UTF8 and cyrillic support you could use [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). But it is a language like HTML, just for PDFs. So you have to generate some source code. It is also possible to embed the desired fonts.